# How should partner have followed up his takeout double under the following circumstances?

Tags: bidding, duplicate-bridge

With only them vulnerable at matchpoints, RHO dealt and passed as did I. LHO opened one club in third seat. Partner doubled (takeout) with the following: ♠ KJ5 ♡AKQJ ♢KJ2 ♣ T53.

I bid one spade, my longest suit. (With the benefit of hindsight, I should have jumped to two spades given my eight high card point, but that's another story.)

Opener rebid two clubs. Partner doubled again. I bid my second suit, two diamonds.  LHO bid three clubs, buying the contract. Partner thought about bidding three hearts but elected to pass.W e got a bottom for "selling out" so low.

I was puzzled by partner's second double. Shouldn't he have raised to two spades with his hand? I would have put him on 16-18 points and raised him to three, which was the lowest level where we belonged. Alternatively, he could have bid two hearts treating his strong four card sequence as "five" (Marty Bergen recommends this.). He might also have raised my diamonds later.

Was any of these actions better than his last "pass?"

Comment: Partner surely can't raise to 2 spades with only 3 spades!  You've "promised" only 4, and there are some hands where you might have only 3 - e.g. Qxx xxx xxx xxxx

Comment: I think we can rule out 3 spades; with no 4-card suit outside of opener's I think it is common to bid the cheapest 3-card suit to keep the auction as low as possible.

Comment: I could agree to bidding a 3 card heart suit in preference to spades but surely not a 3 card diamond suit - people these days commonly make takeout doubles of 1C on something like KQJx KQJx Qx xxx (without agreeing to make offshape takeout doubles in general)

Comment: Stop being so coy; and tell us your hand. Partner has bid the points off his hand; so explain exactly how Partner's 7 loser hand is turning into an expected 9 offensive tricks opposite your near bust two-suiter.

Comment: I figured it out: you're embarrassed to admit you hid your five diamonds Queen in order to show your 4 spades Ace first - completely earning the very well-earned bottom. When will you learn to stop gaming auctions? You must have held something like Axxx x Qxxxx Q9x to make even 3NT playable if the defense isn't sharp.

Comment: @ForgetIwaseverhere: I had Qxxxx 8xx AQxx x. (All x's are 7 or lower). So picked the right "first" suit to bid with longer spades but stronger diamonds. I plead guilty to miscounting points (seven instead of eight) but not to "gaming." I expected partner to raise spades with my five and his three strong ones and 18 high card points. Certainly a second double was the last thing I expected since I ad bid my longest suit. My bidding was "deficient" but not to the extent that you believe

Comment: @TomAu: Goren counts your hand as 10 points. Sheinwold would evaluate it as merely 9+. You underbid your hand by a full king on the response to partner's first double; and by making a minimum call after partner's second double you've denied holding even 4 points, and underbid by two full kings. No partner in the world can recover the partnership after that.

Comment: @ForgetIwaseverhere:Now we're getting closer. So you're saying that I essentially removed the ace of diamonds from my hand and bid only the two queens. Is that right? And why would partner double the second time instead of raising spades?

Comment: @TomAu: Your 1S bid only promises 4 - how can partner raise spades with the 3 they already promised by doubling?  Especially since, in response to a takeout double, you should bid 1S with 4-4 in the majors (because partner is overwhelmingly likely to have 4 in at least one of them).

Comment: @TomAu: It's worse than that. The hand you showed was Qxxxx 8xx 9xxx x.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo: Partner had 18 high card points. Opposite my presumed "four," we'd have 22, which has a fighting chance of making two spades even with a seven card fit. And I might have five. AT which point I would probably have woken up and bid three spades saying, "Oh, I have ore than four points." I'm still puzzled as to why partner doubled a second time. Was he hoping I'd name another suit, perhaps hearts?

Comment: @ForgetIwaseverhere: What second bid should I have made to say, "I claimed no more than seven high card points the first time, but I have the very top of that range, am within shouting distance of "eight" Could I have gone to three spades or even four with my five spades and my "super seven" points?

Comment: @TomAu - yes - the second double hopes you would name a second suit, possibly hearts.  After all,, you could very well have 4-4 in the majors.  It also shows some extra strength, about a king better than a minimum takeout double.

Comment: @TomAu - also, your partner is too strong in high cards for a bid of 2S - in competition that should limit his hand to about 15.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo: According to Goren, a 2S bid over my one spade would show 16-18. Partner's hand was at the top of that range. Or do "moderns" think differently?

Comment: @TomAu - Moderns think differently *in competition* (when RHO has stuck in a bid) but not otherwise.  Just like everyone now plays 1H-(2D)-3H as showing 2-6 hcp (or 0-9 hcp) and 4 hearts (with stronger raises bidding 3D).

Comment: @TomAu - read my response below - all direct raises in competition (i.e. when partner will have another chance to bid if you pass) are based on Law of Total Tricks if that makes sense (but jumps are still strength showing if you couldn't have that many trump based on previous bidding).

Comment: I would have bid 1NT instead of the initial X with your partner's hand. I don't have a club stopper, but Systems On, so the likelihood that if they really have a long club suit you will bid Stayman or transfer to a major are high.

Answer (score 1):

It's one thing to overcall 1H on AKQJ, and another to double and the bid hearts. I'm sympathetic to partner's course of action. Would you like to play at the three level across from Qxxx xx xxxx Qxx, with trumps likely breaking badly? 2S at the second turn might work out, but wouldn't you like to keep the hope of game alive in case partner has eg Qxxx xx xxxx AQx (many would choose to bid 1S rather than jump with a minimum, a terrible 4-card suit, and wastage in clubs). If partner has a bust with 5 spades, they can rebid them.

No, the fact is that partner has a difficult hand to bid with more defense than offense. If your partnership was supposed to compete another level higher, it's your fault for misbidding your hand and putting partner in an impossible situation.

Answer (score 0):

After (1A)-X-(?)-1B-(P), a raise to 2B does indeed show a king better than a minimum.  However, after (1A)-X-(?)-1B-(some bid), a raise to 2B no longer shows such a strong hand; it just shows a hand with 4 B's.  That's because letting the opponents play a 2 level contract when you have an 8 card fit is very likely to get you +50 (or -90) instead of +110, a disaster at matchpoints.  In the first case, you have a possibility of buying the contract at 1B (and a second chance to come in if the opponents bid again); in the second case you don't.

All direct raises in competition are weak if you can have sufficient undisclosed length.